# Where to get db2 express-c 10.1 version

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to download db2-express-c 10.1 version.
But,there is only db2 express-c 11.1 version in ibm-site . And i don't know why ibm-site has no other version's download site. 
Where can i get 10.1 version? 
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IBM only offers a current DB2 Express-C version for download. It is free and has community support, but it only has the current code for download on the IBM website and usually is available some days after the other editions have been GA.

You would need to ask other developers in your community if they still have that image. I would recommend using DB2 11.1 as it has more features and several updates. It is compatible to the V10.1 you have been asking for.